# Removing progress bar from an audio file

Tags: html

I have created an audio file, which starts by pressing the play button. As of right now the way the audio is shown allows participants to go backward and forward and listen to any part of the audio (see picture below). I am trying to find a way to either remove the progress bar completely and only show the play and volume button, or at least disable the possibility for participants to forward or backward on the audio.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdMZ3.png)

Comment: This didn't work... Look at the code I have so far: 
<audio class="qmedia" controls="true" height="40" preload="auto" width="320"><source src="https://knox.co1.qualtrics.com/CP/File.php?F=F_6igWVXYa90A3Wex" type="audio/mp3" /><embed class="qmedia" flashconsts="file=https://knox.co1.qualtrics.com/CP/File.php?F=F_6igWVXYa90A3Wex&amp;width=320&amp;height=20&amp;type=mp3&amp;autostart=false" height="20" pluginspage="http://adobe.com/flashplayer/" src="/WRQualtricsShared/Flash/flvplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="320" wmode="transparent" /></audio>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-webkit-media-controls-timeline` to specify whether you want to display it or not. This works for both video and audio, but we will be using it for the audio as you specified. We use the `display` attribute to hide the progress bar.

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline, -webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Updated my answer with explanation

Comment: So that will work only for `Webkit` based browsers, right?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Correct